# oData's skip() and top() pulling entire record set before filtering

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, odata, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-web-api-odata

i have an oData enabled web api function

```
[EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<StoreCommand> Get()
    {
        return _storeCommandService.GetAllStoreCommands().AsQueryable();
    }
```

the service layer calling Mongodb based Repository pattern's implementation.

```
public IEnumerable<StoreCommand> GetAllStoreCommands()
    {
        return _uow.StoreCommands.GetAll();
    }
```

where GetAll is implemented in Repository layer like

```
    public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _collection.FindAllAs<TEntity>().ToList();
    }
```

where _collection is a MongoCollection of c# driver.

when i make a  call like

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/storeCommandsrest?$skip=0&$top=10&$orderby=Name
```

i get top 10 records but it pulls all the records from the DB and send me back top 10.
Please guide how we can pull only the required set from  the DB.

Comment: Remove `ToList` and return `IEnumerable<T>` on your repository

Comment: so now whats happening is it takes less then a second to go through

all the layers and returns back from api controller but then i takes good 10 or so seconds to display json of 10 records out of 100,000 records. 

it looks like somewhere it is still pulling all records and filtering 10 from them.

Comment: You aren't returning an IQueryable from GetAllStoreCommands(). Your return type must be an IQueryable<StoreCommand>(). To get that from MongoDB, it should be _collection.AsQueryable().

Comment: now i have _collection.FindAllAs<TEntity>().AsQueryable() in repository which is then returning the same from service layer and i get this error

The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for .... A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:0 }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", Type : \"Unknown\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified.....

Comment: i had an older version of Microsoft.data.odata which i now updated to 5.6.4 i didnt had microsoft.datra.services.client, i installed it. i also wasnt using  MongoDB.Driver.Linq; now i am using it.
but it still takes more than 6 to 7 seconds to pull up just 10 records. which looks like it is pulling up all the records somewhere.

Comment: i got it working as required. i had to do 

_collection.AsQueryable();

as you said. 
i would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment moved to answer:

You aren't returning an IQueryable from GetAllStoreCommands(). Your return type must be an IQueryable(). To get that from the driver, it should be _collection.AsQueryable().